# Model.fit "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a NN from a tutroial that I am following but when I run the code I always get this error and I don't know if I am searching for the solution correctly.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import to_categorical

label_map = {label:num for num, label in enumerate(signs)}
label_map

sequences, labels = [], []
for sign in signs:
    for sequence in range(no_sequences):
        window = []
        for frame_no in range(sequence_length):
            res = np.load(os.path.join(Data_Path, sign, str(sequence),"{}.npy".format(frame_no)))
            window.append(res)
        sequences.append(window)
        labels.append(label_map[sign])

X = np.array(sequences)
X.shape

y = to_categorical(labels).astype(int)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

log_dir = os.path.join('Logs')
tb_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir = log_dir)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation="relu", input_shape=(30,1662)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation="relu"))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(signs.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['categorical accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2000, callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

```
{
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "'NoneType' object is not callable",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\\Self-Learning\\Sync's Interns\\Sign Language Classifier\\Sign Language Classifier.ipynb Cell 30 line 1
----> <a href='vscode-notebook-cell:/d%3A/Self-Learning/Sync%27s%20Interns/Sign%20Language%20Classifier/Sign%20Language%20Classifier.ipynb#X41sZmlsZQ%3D%3D?line=0'>1</a> model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2000, callbacks=[tb_callback])

File c:\\Users\\yamen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\\Users\\yamen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\eager\\polymorphic_function\\polymorphic_function.py:857, in Function._call(self, *args, **kwds)
    854   self._lock.release()
    855   # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    856   # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 857   return self._no_variable_creation_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    858 elif self._variable_creation_fn is not None:
    859   # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
    860   # in parallel.
    861   self._lock.release()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
}
```

Honestly I didn't find much useful info on the error and if you have any advice for how to tackle these errors moving forward please tell me.

I tried using this

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['categorical accuracy'])
```

instead of

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['categorical accuracy'])
```

as stated in a previous question.

I also one hot incoded the y_train and y_test data as stated in a previous question.

Comment: Please show more code. The error comes from the `model.fit` method. What happens before that? What is the model?

Comment: I added more code as you asked

Comment: What is `X_train.shape` for your data? Also, `categorical accuracy` should be `categorical_accuracy` (underscore instead of whitespace), but that threw another error for me.

Comment: The underscore solved the problem thank you!